# Getting error when converting seconds to minutes in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I try to convert seconds to minutes, but I'm getting an error:

```py
def convert(seconds): 
    seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600) 
    hour = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60

    return "%dh:%02dm" % (hour, minutes)
```

Here I try to convert seconds to hours and minutes:

```py
def get_total_movingtime(self, obj):
    totalpieces = WorkDay.objects.filter().aggregate(total_movingtime=Round(Sum(convert('foot_time'))))
    return totalpieces["total_movingtime"]
```

The given error is: `"not all arguments converted during string formatting"`.
How to resolve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `convert` function try changing return to this:

```py
return "{}h:{}m".format(hour, minutes)
```

It is just another way of formatting strings. Maybe it will fix it.